# Are all special linear spaces representations of the complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

The real linear space of matrices $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&-c\\c&a\end{bmatrix},$$ with $a$ and $c$ real numbers, which satisfy the conditions (i) $\det(A)\geq0$ and (ii) $\det(A)=0\to A=0$, is a representation of the complex numbers. Is that true for all (special) spaces of $n\times n$ matrices satisfying these two conditions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No: consider the 3-dimensional space of matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & b & c\\ -a & 0 & c & -b\\ -b & -c & 0 & a\\ -c & b & -a & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\det(A)=\operatorname{Pf}(A)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 $.

Comment: Or for that matter the Hamilton quaternions, which are obtained from your $A$'s by adding an arbitrary multiple of the identity.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Could one have octonions also, and that's all?

Comment: @efferrari You can take any linear subspace of the quaternions, or various collections of skew-symmetric matrices using the Pfaffian as in the answer.  Octonions are not associative and thus not realizable as a matrix ring.

Comment: @efferrari There are many more examples. For instance, a vector space with a positive quadratic form, say of dimension $n$, acts by multiplication on its Clifford algebra; this gives a $n$-dimensional vector space of $2^n\times 2^n$ matrices with your property.

Comment: @Kimball Thank you! From the beautiful example given by abx, I think now that multiplication is not an issue, in the sense that multiplication by a complex number is equivalent to a dilatation and a rotation in the complex plane and in the given example the rotation is in the 3D space of vectors (a,b,c). The existence of such a symmetry is a crucial issue.

Comment: @abx Very nice! Thank you. The vectors (matrices) in the special space should be transformed (remaining in the space) but their determinant would be invariant. Do you know examples with another Lie groups?